# What do you call someone who misses someone?

Tags: single-word-requests

What would you call a person who misses someone dearly? 
Perhaps also a person who's life was changed by that person?

Comment: Adjective could be 'bereft'.  Are you looking for a noun or would an adjective do?

Comment: Hmm... I'm trying to describe someone but at the same time using that word to call someone... so I am probably looking for a noun and/or adjective.

Comment: Can you create an example sentence of how you want to use it?

Comment: An old-fashioned word that may be relevant is _lorn_, which Merriam-Webster says means "desolate, forsaken." It most often comes up today as part of the word _lovelorn_, meaning (according to MW) "bereft of love or of a lover."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"[Lovesick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lovesickness)" can describe someone who loves someone and is unrequited in that love but it can also mean that they miss someone who they love who is away from them... like "homesick".

> Lovesickness describes the informal syndrome of rejected or unrequited love or the absence of a loved one and covers physical as well as mental symptoms. It is not to be confused with the condition of being lovestruck. Although typically harmless it can for some personalities lead to serious physical or mental illness, sometimes even culminating in attempted suicide. In psychology, lovesickness is seldom acknowledged.

Alternately, "[pine/pining](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/american-english/pine)"

> to strongly desire esp. something that is difficult or impossible to obtain:
>
> - Bradley pined for his wife, who was far away.

Comment: I'm glad you like the answer but you would be wise to wait for other options!  There may be better ones I've not thought of here.